# NSUserDefaults nothing save when i NSLog it

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nslog

I am trying to save my `NSMutableArray` data into `NSUserDefaults`, but after it is done in my Log is still `(null)` value. 
Is something wrong with my code?

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
NSUserDefaults*defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:self.FlipsideView.myMutableArray forKey:@"NSMutableArray"];
[defaults synchronize];
NSLog(@"tableview data: %@", self.FlipsideView.myMutableArray);
NSLog(@"tableview data: %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"NSMutableArray"]);
}
```

and here is my debug result:

```
2013-09-20 15:10:08.914 Milosova[4033:a0b] tableview data: (null)
2013-09-20 15:10:08.915 Milosova[4033:a0b] tableview data: (null)
```

here is code from my ViewController where i put some numbers into textFields:

```
- (void)counter:(id)sender{

double value1 = [litre.text doubleValue];
double value2 = [kilometer.text doubleValue];
double result = (value1 / value2) * 100;
self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2lf", result];
function*newCell = [[function alloc] initWithName:self.litre.text done:NO];
[self.flipsideView.myMutableArray addObject:newCell];
newCell = [[function alloc] initWithName:self.kilometer.text done:NO];
[self.flipsideView.myMutableArray addObject:newCell];
newCell = [[function alloc] initWithName:self.display.text done:NO];
[self.flipsideView.myMutableArray addObject:newCell];
[self.flipsideView.tableView reloadData];
}
```

and this is my function code:

```
-(id)initWithName:(NSString *)name done:(BOOL)done{
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    self.name = _name;
    self.done = _done;
}
return self;
}
```

i put in into tableView via prepareForsegue method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"route"]) {
    UINavigationController *navi = segue.destinationViewController;
    MainViewController*controller = [navi.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    controller.flipsideView = self;

} }
```

Comment: You are trying to add nil data to a dictionary.

Comment: No idea, show us how did you add and we'll see.

Comment: Are you allocating the `NSMutableArray` somewhere before you add the objects? Something like `[[self flipsideView] setMyMutableArray:[NSMutableArray array]];`

Comment: i just allocate that array in my tableViewController in viewDidLoad method. { myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] }

Comment: I cant find out over two weeks. I am new in xcode, so any help appreciated.

Comment: Desdenova if you give me your mail, i can send you whole project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Desdenova pointed out, the array you are trying to add is nil, so of course the content you add to user defaults will also be nil.

You need to add a valid property list object to user defaults. Nil objects, or objects that are not property list objects will not save.

If you think self.FlipsideView.myMutableArray should be non-nil, you need to go trace through the code that creates and populates that array.

If the property is declared as weak or unsafe_unretained that is your problem. It's getting deallocated.

Comment: property myMutableArray is (nonatomic, strong). Did you mean this property?

Comment: But when i used NSLog in my perepareForSegue method, myMutableArray have 4 objects.. How is possible, that when i want store it into NSUserDefaults, than is empty?

Answer (score 0):

One more thing is missing in your code you are not synchronizing `NSUserDefaults` try to use below lines of code

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: I have [defaults synchronize]; its the same? I forgot it, but still empty